# Alter query in cassandra no sql

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

While using alter query in Cassandra I am able to add data to newly added column and it creates another duplicate field for that particular entry.

While using batch query I am not able to delete the particular field.

[image]

Comment: specify your partition key,clustering column . Also specify the query you made which caused you duplication

Comment: primarykey is song name and song id. alter query.  ALTER table musicplaylist  
add column  hero text;      update musicplaylist set hero='pawankalyan' where songid=1 and songname='vayyarala';

Comment: what is your clustering column? I m sure this may be the distinguishing factor